# "The CPU implementation of FusedBatchNorm only supports NHWC tensor format for now."

Tags: python-3.x, tensorflow, keras, tf.keras

I am trying to recreate a model and re-produce its published results. I use TF 2.0 and the model I think was coded with Theano backend. The model came from this [repo](https://github.com/j05t/mnist) in github, for context.

I also do not use `tensorflow-gpu` as it is not compatible with my hardware setup.

Anyway, at first I've encountered a lot of error trying to load its weights or even the model. When I realized the save/load functions are just messed up, I moved on to trying to just load and train the model. Since I use Tensorflow, I modified the code to use the `'channels_last'` format, or `NHWC`, as the error says so.

Here's my import list:

```py
from __future__ import absolute_import
from __future__ import division
from __future__ import print_function
from __future__ import unicode_literals

from tensorflow import keras

import cv2
import os
import pathlib
import shutil

import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np
import tensorflow as tf
```

The modified model:

```py
def createModel():
    model = keras.models.Sequential()
    model.add(keras.layers.Lambda(norm_input, input_shape=(28,28,1), output_shape=(28,28,1)))
    model.add(keras.layers.Conv2D(32, (3,3)))
    model.add(keras.layers.LeakyReLU())
    model.add(keras.layers.BatchNormalization(axis=1))
    model.add(keras.layers.Conv2D(32, (3,3)))
    model.add(keras.layers.LeakyReLU())
    model.add(keras.layers.MaxPooling2D())
    model.add(keras.layers.BatchNormalization(axis=1))
    model.add(keras.layers.Conv2D(64, (3,3)))
    model.add(keras.layers.LeakyReLU())
    model.add(keras.layers.BatchNormalization(axis=1))
    model.add(keras.layers.Conv2D(64, (3,3)))
    model.add(keras.layers.LeakyReLU())
    model.add(keras.layers.MaxPooling2D())
    model.add(keras.layers.Flatten())
    model.add(keras.layers.BatchNormalization())
    model.add(keras.layers.Dense(512))
    model.add(keras.layers.LeakyReLU())
    model.add(keras.layers.BatchNormalization())
    model.add(keras.layers.Dropout(0.3))
    model.add(keras.layers.Dense(10, activation='softmax'))

    model.compile(optimizer='adam', loss='categorical_crossentropy', metrics=['accuracy'])

    return model
```

How I loaded and preprocessed the MNIST dataset:

```py
(x_train, y_train), (x_test, y_test) = keras.datasets.mnist.load_data()

test_labels = y_test

x_train = x_train.reshape(x_train.shape[0], 28, 28, 1)
x_test = x_test.reshape(x_test.shape[0], 28, 28, 1)

x_train = x_train.astype(np.float32)
x_test = x_test.astype(np.float32)

x_train /= 255
x_test /= 255

y_train = keras.utils.to_categorical(y_train, 10)
y_test = keras.utils.to_categorical(y_test, 10)
```

The `ImageDataGenerator`:

```py
    gen = keras.preprocessing.image.ImageDataGenerator(
            rotation_range=12, 
            width_shift_range=0.1, 
            shear_range=0.3,
            height_shift_range=0.1, 
            zoom_range=0.1, 
            data_format='channels_last')
```

And lastly, the function to train the models:

```py
def fit_model(m):
    m.fit_generator(batches, steps_per_epoch=steps_per_epoch, epochs=1, verbose=0,
                   validation_data=test_batches, validation_steps=validation_steps)
    m.optimizer.lr = 0.1
    m.fit_generator(batches, steps_per_epoch=steps_per_epoch, epochs=4, verbose=0,
                   validation_data=test_batches, validation_steps=validation_steps)
    m.optimizer.lr = 0.01
    m.fit_generator(batches, steps_per_epoch=steps_per_epoch, epochs=12, verbose=0,
                   validation_data=test_batches, validation_steps=validation_steps)
    m.optimizer.lr = 0.001
    m.fit_generator(batches, steps_per_epoch=steps_per_epoch, epochs=18, verbose=0,
                   validation_data=test_batches, validation_steps=validation_steps)
    return m
```

The last code snippet is where the error points to, but I don't know what exactly broke there that's related to the image format. Specifically, it points at the third line, or the line that starts with the `validation_data=...`.

The full error is:

```py
Component function execution failed: Internal: The CPU implementation of FusedBatchNorm only supports NHWC tensor format for now.
     [[{{node batch_normalization_v2/cond/then/_0/FusedBatchNorm}}]]
```

And traceback:

```py
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "model3.py", line 113, in <module>
    m = fit_model(createModel())
  File "model3.py", line 52, in fit_model
    validation_data=test_batches, validation_steps=validation_steps)
  File "/home/ren/.local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/tensorflow/python/keras/engine/training.py", line 1515, in fit_generator
    steps_name='steps_per_epoch')
  File "/home/ren/.local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/tensorflow/python/keras/engine/training_generator.py", line 257, in model_iteration
    batch_outs = batch_function(*batch_data)
  File "/home/ren/.local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/tensorflow/python/keras/engine/training.py", line 1259, in train_on_batch
    outputs = self._fit_function(ins)  # pylint: disable=not-callable
  File "/home/ren/.local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/tensorflow/python/keras/backend.py", line 3217, in __call__
    outputs = self._graph_fn(*converted_inputs)
  File "/home/ren/.local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/tensorflow/python/eager/function.py", line 558, in __call__
    return self._call_flat(args)
  File "/home/ren/.local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/tensorflow/python/eager/function.py", line 627, in _call_flat
    outputs = self._inference_function.call(ctx, args)
  File "/home/ren/.local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/tensorflow/python/eager/function.py", line 415, in call
    ctx=ctx)
  File "/home/ren/.local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/tensorflow/python/eager/execute.py", line 66, in quick_execute
    six.raise_from(core._status_to_exception(e.code, message), None)
  File "<string>", line 3, in raise_from
tensorflow.python.framework.errors_impl.InternalError: The CPU implementation of FusedBatchNorm only supports NHWC tensor format for now.
     [[{{node batch_normalization_v2/cond/then/_0/FusedBatchNorm}}]] [Op:__inference_keras_scratch_graph_3602]
```

I'd expect it to be fixed when I added the line `tf.keras.backend.set_image_data_format('channels_last')` at the top of my code. I also even put the same argument in the `ImageDataGenerator` mentioned earlier for good measure. So I honestly don't have any idea what I've missed or where I went wrong.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**DISCLAIMER**

I am only a **novice** in this area, and have only based **this answer** on what I've **read in the docs**. I have **no full understanding** of the **possible repercussions and its extent to the model**; at worst, it may **affect its performance and accuracy**. At best, this solution can be considered only a **makeshift patch** to **suppress the error**, at least until someone else confirms it as otherwise. Any confirmations, clarifications, suggestions, and alternate solutions are always welcome.

From [Keras documentation](https://keras.io/layers/normalization/#batchnormalization) on `BatchNormalization`:

> **axis**: Integer, the axis that should be normalized (typically the features axis). For instance, after a `Conv2D` layer with `data_format="channels_first"`, set `axis=1` in `BatchNormalization`.

Since I use `channels_last` or `NHWC` as image format, simply equating `axis` to `-1` in the parameter fixed it. To be clear:

`keras.layers.BatchNormalization(axis=-1)`

Fixed my problem.

Answer (score 1):

if you want to operate Batch Normalization on the first axis this little trick override the error:

replace: `model.add(keras.layers.BatchNormalization(axis=1))`

with:

```
model.add(keras.layers.Permute((2, 3, 1)))
model.add(keras.layers.BatchNormalization(axis=-1))
model.add(keras.layers.Permute((3, 1, 2)))
```